# Realm documentation says that there is user object which contain flexibleSyncConfiguration method but actually it doesn't exist

Tags: ios, realm, atlas-device-sync

below I will try to use user.flexibleSyncConfiguration, but it does not exit , but documentation. says it is, I use latest realm sdk 10.44.
What is the issue over here?

```
@MainActor
func openSyncedRealm(user: User) async {
    do {
        var config = user.flexibleSyncConfiguration(initialSubscriptions: { subs in
            subs.append(
                QuerySubscription<Todo> {
                    $0.ownerId == user.id
                })
        })
        // Pass object types to the Flexible Sync configuration
        // as a temporary workaround for not being able to add a
        // complete schema for a Flexible Sync app.
        config.objectTypes = [Todo.self]
        let realm = try await Realm(configuration: config, downloadBeforeOpen: .always)
        useRealm(realm, user)
    } catch {
        print("Error opening realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I tried to use synced user but it does not exist in realm swift.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. When you say - *it does not exist* - can you clarify what that means? Is an error being thrown or perhaps config is nil? Or does it not compile at all? Or perhaps you didn't authenticate the user first so nil is passed in the `user` parameter? Please update the **question** with more details so the question is not closed.

Comment: I mean to say that there is no method name flexibleSyncConfiguration there.

Comment: Did you `import RealmSwift` at the top of file?

Comment: Yes all the thing is done

``import Foundation
import RealmSwift``

Comment: As a test I created a XCode 15.2 Swift Project. Then crafted a podfile (per the Realm guide) and added it to the project. In the main viewController, I added `import RealmSwift` at the top and copy and pasted this code [useRealm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/sync/add-sync-to-app/#use-the-realm) and then the code in your question [Add Sync](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/sync/add-sync-to-app/#open-a-synced-realm). Built and ran the project with no errors. Duplicated the process with SPM. Everything works correctly and no issue with `user.flexibleSyncConfiguration`.

Comment: I got to thinking about this and perhaps there's a naming collision going on with the `User` object? Meaning that if there's another library with an object called `User` that be overriding the Realm version. So. Try specifying which User object to use: `func openSyncedRealm(user: RealmSwift.User) async {` e.g. change the user parameter from `User` to `RealmSwift.User`.